# Deleting registry doesn't seem to take effect

Tags: c#, registry, startup

The following code deleted the registry key but never enters the for loop (Which it should enter since it checks whether the value was deleted or not) why is that happening? (I am using windows 10 - 64 bit)
When I navigate to `LocalMachine\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run` I don't see any `HackerOne` scanner value there! (I checked just after I create it)

```
    RegistryKey rk1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
    rk1.DeleteValue("HackerOne Scanner", false);
    if (Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", "true", true) == null)
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
            rk.SetValue("HackerOne Scanner", Application.ExecutablePath);
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("Admin Rights Are Required"); Application.Exit(); }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", "true", true)
```

returns `true` when the value wasn't found, not `null`, because you passed `true` as the default value. But you can pass `null` as the default value.

```
Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", "true", null);
```

Notice however, that you're searching for an other value than the value you then set, `true` vs `"HackerOne Scanner"`. That might not be intentional.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I have small question, here I tried to catch an error then show a message box and exit the form using Application.Exit() but the form doesn't exit, do you know why?

Comment: That should be a new question. Show the code there.